# Screenshot seems to be messed up on PhantomJS

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

Screenshot is seems to be messed up on PhantomJS, I am using selenium 3.3.1 and PhantomJS 2.1.1.

**Code snippet:**

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs();
    caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    caps.setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);

     WebDriver driver =  new PhantomJSDriver(caps);

    String screenShot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BASE64);
```

Comment: Try setting the browser window to maximized via code after instantiation and before the screenshot.

Comment: try using some wait